# Missing nodes in Neo4j with "Neo4j Kafka Connector Sink"

Tags: apache-kafka, neo4j, apache-kafka-connect

I have setup my Kafka connector by following [Neo4j Documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/kafka-streams/quickstart-connect/) and testing the connector by publishing messages using Kafka and expecting the message to be transformed to a Neo4j node. Here is my Sink configuration,

```
{
            "name": "SomeName",
            "config": {
            "topics": "SomeTopicName",
            "connector.class": "streams.kafka.connect.sink.Neo4jSinkConnector",
            "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
            "key.converter.schemas.enable": false,
            "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
            "value.converter.schemas.enable": false,
            "errors.retry.timeout": "-1",
            "errors.retry.delay.max.ms": "1000",
            "errors.tolerance": "all",
            "errors.log.enable": true,
            "errors.log.include.messages": true,
            "neo4j.database": "someDb",
            "neo4j.server.uri": "neo4j://X.X.X.X:XXXX",
            "neo4j.authentication.basic.username": "neo4j",
            "neo4j.authentication.basic.password": "password",
            "neo4j.batch.parallelize": false,
            "neo4j.connection.max.pool.size": 500,
            "neo4j.topic.cypher.SomeTopicName": "query"
}
```

The basic injection works fine, like broadcasting 10k messages is showing 10k nodes in Neo4j. But, when I broadcast 500k messages, I see only 350kh nodes in Neo4j. I don't see any error in connector logs or Neo4j logs. If I run the broadcast with the same set of 500k nodes again, missing nodes are added. Like I need to repeat this run until I see the complete 500k nodes in Neo4j.

### Expected behavior

I want to see all nodes in Neo4j or an error for missing nodes

### Actual behavior

Streamed Kafka messages are missing in Neo4j Database

### How to reproduce the problem

I used basic cypher query,

```
//Insert here a set of Cypher statements that helps us to reproduce the problem

MERGE(person:Person {uri: 'http://company#Person/' + event.personid}) 
    ON MATCH SET person.hasdescription=event.hasdescription, person.hascount=event.hascount 
    ON CREATE SET person.hasdescription=person.hasdescription, person.hascount=event.hascount  return count(*) as count
```

#### Steps

1. Create a connector
2. Broadcast message to topic
3. Check in Neo4j

#### Versions

- OS: Centos
- neo4j:5-enterprise
- confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:7.3.0
- cnfldemos/cp-server-connect-datagen:0.6.0-7.3.0
- confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.3.0
- confluentinc/cp-server:7.3.0
- confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.3.0

I tried to broadcast to more messages like 500k and expect 500k nodes to get created. But, I see nodes are missing.

Comment: What happens when you remove the `ON MATCH` query? You've not said you're creating unique records

Comment: Please use universal measurements / words instead of local words like *lakh*. Not everyone is going to understand that, and it's going to be very confusing that what are the *lakh nodes* you're talking about.

Comment: why do you expect 500k nodes, do all the messages contain information about different nodes

Comment: @OneCricketeer its same after removing ON MATCH. Yes, I am creating unique records.

Comment: @TomažBratanič I am trying to stream messages from different sources and persisting in Neo4j. I am testing this flow to make sure if all the streamed messages are correctly loaded to Neo4j.

Comment: Change MERGE to CREATE and see if the problem is the same?

Comment: Can you share your producer code as a [mcve]? Where does `personid` get generated? (The connect-datagen connector isn't guaranteed to create globally unique events, I dont think)